# How can auto play carousel in SAP/spartacus?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am using carousel components of SAP/spartacus. My requirement is carousel should be auto play.
Please help me to resolve it.

Comment: Someone has an idea of Spartacus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see in the source code it's not implemented OOTB in Spartacus, but you can easily add this functionality to your project.

Please create your own `CarouselComponent`, based on Spartacus' one.

1 class should implement also `OnDestroy` interface

2 add new dependency `protected ref: ChangeDetectorRef`

3 add new property `subscription = new Subscription();`

4 fill method `ngOnInit` by this:

```
    super.ngOnInit();
    this.subscription = this.size$
      .pipe(
        take(1),
        switchMap((size) =>
          interval(5000).pipe(
            tap(() => {
              this.activeSlide =
                this.activeSlide > this.items.length - size - 1
                  ? 0
                  : this.activeSlide + size;
              this.ref.markForCheck();
            })
          )
        )
      )
      .subscribe();
```

5 remember about `ngOnDestroy() { this.subscription.unsubscribe(); }`

---

Then prepare your own version of `BannerCarouselComponent` (change the only template - use your new carousel component instead `cx-carousel`)

At the end, set:

```
      cmsComponents: {
        RotatingImagesComponent: {
          component: YourBannerCarouselComponent,
        },
      },
```